# Call to undefined method Memcached::getAllKeys() on PHP7

Tags: php, memcached, fatal-error, php-7

I have this script

```
 $prefix = "feed_";
 $keys = @$memcached->getAllKeys();
 foreach ($keys as $index => $key) {
   if (strpos($key,$prefix) !== 0) { 
     unset($keys[$index]); 
   } else { 
     $memcached->delete($key);
   }
 }
```

that return this fatal error: *Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method stdClass::getAllKeys()*.

If I run PHP5.* all works fine. But with PHP7.* it's not the same.
I don't find anything about deprecated function http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.getallkeys.php

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: It's checking on `stdClass`, which sounds like `$memcached` was not initialized properly.

Comment: `Memcached` is a PECL extension. Are you sure it's installed in your PHP7 environment? Remember, they have to be recompiled for PHP7 if you compiled them yourself (or have the correct DLL installed). You should have a `memcache` section under `phpinfo()`